# Create a proper partition table for ubuntu installation with 128GB SSD and 1TB HDD

Tags: 20.04, boot-partition

I have a Dell Laptop which has 128GB SDD and 1TB HDD with Windows OS installed. I want to delete the Windows OS and migrate to Ubuntu 20.04. Can anyone please tell me what will be a perfect partition table?

Comment: No such thing, Every one uses their computer for something different and therefore has different ideas of perfect. Personally I went with the defaults. Someone else would call me crazy.

Comment: Backup Windows. We regularly get users who want to reinstall Windows for one game or one application they absolutely have to have that does not work in Linux.

Comment: Maybe use the ssd as "/" and your hdd as "/home/"? I have a pc with that partition layout. ssd speed for programs and os, hdd capacity for photo's, footage, completed video's, minecraft worlds, ......

Comment: I'd recommend creating a dual-boot Windows/Ubuntu configuration, as you'll need Windows to run things that you can't run on Ubuntu... like BIOS/firmware updates. Don't manually partition the disk for the Ubuntu install, let the installer do it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This section of the Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Partitioning#Discrete_partitions) can give you some insight into some sensible paths to dedicate a separate partition to.

This said, everyone has different needs and preferences, so there cannot be a perfect way of partitioning your disk.

I think that if you had the need for this level of granularity with your system, you would know how to organize partitions. The link I provided can help you with this if you have a rough idea of what you want to achieve. Otherwise just stick to the default automatic partitioning the Ubuntu installer offers and you'll likely be completely fine.